# Convet this sql query to php laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

SELECT project_name, (CHAR_LENGTH(company_id) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(company_id, ',', '')) + 1) as total FROM project_management;

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
$getData = DB::table('')
    ->selectRaw('write your query here')
    ->where('')
    ->get();
```

Comment: $getData = DB::table('project_management')
    ->selectRaw('project_name, (CHAR_LENGTH(company_id) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(company_id, ',', '')) + 1)') ->get();

Comment: My table name is project_management, column name 'project_name' second column is 'company_id' we want to get char length of customer id

Comment: did you get the data or not....??

Comment: not get the data, and sir check my query is correct or not

Comment: yea...it is correct....!!! try to execute and check whether the result is coming or not...!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$getData = DB::table('project_management')
->selectRaw('(CHAR_LENGTH(company_id) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(company_id, ',', '')) 
+ 1) as total')
->addSelect('project_name')
->get();
```